# Linux web cam with time and date?

Tags: linux, video, webcam, vlc-media-player

How to record video from webcam with added date and time? VLC and cheese cat't do it.

Comment: Question for SU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I didn't notice you already tried cheese.

FFMpeg can do it.

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -s 640x480 -r 30 -vf \
"drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \
text='\%T': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460" -vcodec libx264 -vb 2000k \
-preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4
```

Its not very user friendly, but here is a page that can help,
[Adding time stamp overlay to video stream using ffmpeg](http://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/)
and I'm sure there are more.